# Forgot to add column in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Forgot to add the following column to a table.  I'm using SQL server syntax, but not sure how to stick everything in one command.

Before I alter anything, I wanted to make sure the following code would add the column properly.

```
ALTER TABLE Player
ADD column country varchar(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL;
```

Can I get away with the command above or do I have to `ADD Contraint` before `UNIQUE` AND `NOT NULL`?

The column in question is below.

```
Type              Value

Column Name       Country
Key Type          NULL/UNIQUE
Datatype          VARCHAR
Length            50
```

Comment: Does the table have any rows in it?

Comment: if yes Constraints will not going to apply on table

Comment: What does the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) tell you?

Comment: Also you only allow one player per country?

Comment: The documentation is confusing.  Not clear whether I can just tack on `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL` after I add the column.

Comment: Yes, one player per country.

Comment: Table has data in it, yes.

Comment: So that isn't going to work then because your new column will have `NULL` for all existing rows violating the `NOT NULL` constraint (and violating the unique constraint if more than one row exists). Also it is just `ADD` not `ADD column`

Comment: So can I just drop the `NOT NULL` and my statement will be valid?

Comment: No. Because that only fixes one of the three issues.

Comment: So I dropped the `NOT NULL`, the `ADD column` to `ADD` and what was the last issue?

Comment: Why are you asking us to validate your syntax? Just set up a test table with a couple of rows and try it.

Comment: Don't have access to the database currently.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you have data in your table already that you cannot afford to lose, then you will need to create the new column non unique and nullable. perform your update and then modify it with your constraints.

Another solution would be to have a child table that keys off of this one. You can keep your constraints in place with this solution, but unless you can't do it the other way, I wouldn't recommend this approach.